# databases not visible in mysql workbench sidebar

Tags: mysql, database, wampserver

It started with installation of wampserver for php, before that I had already running MySQL server 5.7 with all databases properly showing in the side schema panel. When I launched MySQL server after installation of wampserver 5.7.14, the password for root was overridden and no database except sys is showing. Also I found another user (mysql.sys) has been created (found in Users and Privileges). Then I looked for databases in path "ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data", all databases are present in the folder (thank god they are not deleted). Problem is now for my website I get this error:

"Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration"

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

I know this is not related to migrations because my database already exists but I don't know how to solve the problem that MySQL can see the databases in its "ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data" again.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed WAMPServer on a system that already had a MYSQL Server instance installed on it, you created a second MySQL Server instance. See your service you will have one called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` and another called `MYSQL`.

Now, whichever service you start first will be the MySQL Server that Workbench, or anything else is talking to. And you will only see the databases that this MySQL Server instance knows about.

#### Correct Solution:

- Stop WAMPServer
- Start the MYSQL installed with Workbench
- Backup all YOUR databases, NOT the ones created by MySQL like `mysql`, `sys`, `information_schema`, `performance_schema`
- Stop this MYSQL Server.
- Uninstall this MySQL Server
- Start WAMPServer
- Restore your databases to this MySQL Server instance
- All should start working as expected now.
- Connect your Workbench to WAMPServers MySQL Server

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Did a robust workaround, though not very suggestible but database is now accessible in MySQL workbench. Though I'm having the same error when opening the website on local web server. One thing that I did not mention before that environment is Windows based. what I did is copied database from the ProgramData MySQL path to "..\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\data" path and refreshed schema in workbench. Any advice why I'm still having problem in web server.